# Select duplicated lists from a list of lists (Python 2.7.13)

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists, one is a list of lists, and they have the same number of indexes(the half number of values), like this:

```
list1=[['47', '43'], ['299', '295'], ['47', '43'], etc.]
list2=[[9.649, 9.612, 9.42, etc.]
```

I want to detect the repeated pair of values in the same list(and delete it), and sum the values with the same indexes in the second list, creating an output like this:

```
list1=[['47', '43'], ['299', '295'], etc.]
list2=[[19.069, 9.612, etc.]
```

The main problem is that the order of the values is important and I'm really stuck.

Comment: unclear, can be more elaborate ? an example would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `collections.defaultdict` to sum values together, with keys as the sublists (converted as `tuple` to be hashable)

```
list1=[['47', '43'], ['299', '295'], ['47', '43']]
list2=[9.649, 9.612, 9.42]

import collections

c = collections.defaultdict(float)

for l,v in zip(list1,list2):
    c[tuple(l)] += v

print(c)
```

Alternative using `collections.Counter` and which does the same:

```
c = collections.Counter((tuple(k),v) for k,v in zip(list1,list2))
```

At this point, we have the related data:

```
defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {('299', '295'): 9.612, ('47', '43'): 19.069})
```

now if needed (not sure, since the dictionary holds the data very well) we can rebuild the lists, keeping the (relative) order between them (but not their original order, that shouldn't be a problem since they're still linked):

```
list1=[]
list2=[]

for k,v in c.items():
    list1.append(list(k))
    list2.append(v)

print(list1,list2)
```

result:

```
[['299', '295'], ['47', '43']]
[9.612, 19.069]
```

Comment: Thanks, the order that really matters is between them.